# How may I run a user process at system startup that the user can set himself?

Tags: linux, service, users

I would like the users of the system to be able to setup processes that run at system startup that they can setup by themselves. How may I do it?

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Do you actually mean when the system is powered on, or do you mean when the user logs in.  Will the users have admin access to the system?  Will the users be able to specify any process they want.  If they aren't admins and can select any process they want are you willing to accept the risk that they may compromise the security of the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user can specify a script to run on boot via cron. In their crontab (edited by executing 'crontab -e' when logged in), they would specify:

```
@reboot /home/username/path/to/script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask them to add it to rc.local ?

Comment: That will not work as rc.local can only be edited by root

Comment: on a regular system yes, but on his, users are encouraged to add there own processes at startup

Answer (score 0):

Write your own `rc.local` script to check every user `$HOME/rc.local`. Then, use `su` to execute that command under the user account.